# Написание OSCAR/JABBER клиента на Java

Tags: сеть, клиент, java

Здравствуйте. В рамках изучения протоколов OSCAR/JABBER требуется написать упрощенную версию клиента (мессенджер по тип ICQ), работающего по одному из протоколов (на выбор). Подскажите пожалуйста материалы по данному делу. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как [известно](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSCAR_protocol), OSCAR не совсем открытый протокол, поэтому смотрите [исходники мирандовского оскар-плагина на C](http://addons.miranda-im.org/download.php?dlsource=1683).

Answer (score 0):

Лучше пиши jabber клиент - для него есть куча реализаций протокола и он открытый.